# Node.js and npm which word to choose "package" or "module"?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am confused `npm` is a package manager, but `Node.js` has modules. So when you install or create your own... erhmm, module, package? Which word to choose over another and when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at docs http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html :

> In Node, files and modules are in one-to-one correspondence.

On the other hand package is a folder with a special `package.json` file in it. That file tells the interpreter how to load modules when you do `require(folder);`. In other words package is a collection of modules.

Answer (score 2):

In Node, a single file is a module. It is a somewhat isolated entity from other parts of the program and by convention is usually written in a way where it can be run as an independent program (even if it doesn't do anything). On the other hand, a package in node is a larger entity. It is basically a complete program/library that serves some purpose. A package may consist of a single module file or hundreds of files.

The package is traditionally defined by "package.json" in the root directory of a package and it describes the creator's purpose and other things about the program.

Answer (score 1):

If it has `package.json`/`package.yaml` at the top, and it is installable from npm registry, it is definitely a package.

If it's one simple javascript file (maybe a part of your package) written in CommonJS standard, it's a module.

Comment: Package may not be in npm registry. For it to be there someone should explicitly submit his/her package. Many packages are not submitted there and not hosted on Github, but still are valid packages (e.g. as my company keeps our packages on private repositories).